# Spring Boot - gradlew test failed || Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

1. I made my project using [spring website](https://start.spring.io) with the following options:- gradle project, java , spring boot version 2.4.5, java version 8, dependencies:- Spring Web, Thymeleaf, Spring Data API
2. Downloaded the .zip file and extracted it
3. Ran `gradlew test` and it failed with the following report:- [project/build/reports/tests/test](https://github.com/chetan0402/gradlew-test-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no available JDBC driver in your project. When you choose the Spring Data JPA dependency from Spring Initializr, you also need to add a database driver (for example, H2, PostgreSQL or MariaDB). The same is true for Spring Data JDBC and Spring Data R2DBC. [image]